# Mongodb dump on server in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

Pardon if anything is basic, as I am working on mongodb for the first time.
The thing is, I have application running on aws. I need its dump. But Because of mongodb I am not able to find the database name and Other information as it is very secure app. **Mongoid.yml** is something like below,

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: mongodb://prod**:*************@ip-**-**-**:****,ip-**-**-**:****/production
      options:
    consistency: :strong
        safe: true
        auto_discover: false
```

So can anyone tell me how am I supposed to retrieve the database information of the current project. I know the commands for taking dump but not able to figure out the db name. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean, "secure"? All info is there, in the connection string. Database name is "production"

Comment: And other info like username and password?

Comment: yeah, those bits that you masked out.

Comment: so suppose 
uri: mongodb://prod:xyshsdh@ip-20-20-30-20:0000, ip-20-20-30-20:0000/production 
Then, username is prod:xyshsdh? or prod ?

Comment: just prod. password is xyshsdh